# Listing numerical contents of an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, numeric

I am writing a simple program which takes a list of grades and outputs the passing grades in c and lists all the grades from the list (10 grades).

The function to calculate the amount of passing grades and print them is fine.

Printing the contents of the array using printf is where I am having problems.

This is how I input the array:

```
int grades[10] = {70, 80, 95, 65, 35, 85, 54, 78, 45, 68};
```

Currently I am using this (which works):

```
printf ("These are the grades: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d \n", grades[0], grades[1], grades[2], grades[3], grades[4], grades[5], grades[6], grades[7], grades[8], grades[9]);
```

It lists the contents of the array, but I am sure there has to be a more elegant way to print the list w/o pointing to each element of the array specifically.

Is there a more elegant solution that I am unaware of?

I did search the topics and was unable to find an answer, sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: You need to write a function that receives grades as an argument and prints them!

Comment: Using a *loop* springs to mind. And frankly I'm curious how those grades were *input* without one (otherwise the solution would have been obvious).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a control loop (in this case `for`) to print the arbitrary number of items you're targeting. Given an array of N items to print, the following demonstrate this (and produces your exact desired output):

```
int grades[N]; // initialized here or filled later

printf("These are the grades: %d", grades[0]);
for (int i = 1; i  < N; i++) 
    printf(", %d", grades[i]);
fputc('\n', stdout);
```

Note that this methodology allows you to *under-print* the array. You don't have to print *everything*. For example, suppose you have an array that *can* hold `M` items, but only holds `N` (where `0 <= N <= M` holds). Then simply alter the prior algorithm to account for potentially fewer items (including none):

```
if (N > 0)
{
    printf("These are the grades: %d", grades[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i  < N; i++) 
        printf(", %d", grades[i]);
    fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```

You can find out more about the for-loop [**here**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for), as well as many other attributes of the C language. Keep that link around; it's worth the bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function that receives grades as an argument and prints them!

```
void print_array(int* grades, int size) {
   for(int i = 0; i  < size; i++) {
     printf("%d", grades[i]);
   }
}
```